# Azure AD B2C CORS errors

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to run the sample

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp

Part 1 works fine.  I'm trying Part II with my own Azure AD B2C.

I updated *policies.js* file with the URL from my signup user flow and *authconfig.js* with my application id.

```
const b2cPolicies = {
    names: {
        signUpSignIn: "B2C_1_sign_up_sign_in",
    },
    authorities: {
        signUpSignIn: {
            authority: "https://zzz.b2clogin.com/zzz.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_sign_up_sign_in",
        }
```

However I get a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
https://zzz.b2clogin.com/zzz.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_sign_up_sign_in/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:6420' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The sample clearly expects to run from localhost as per the instructions.  Is there anything missing in my config? any ideas?

The fact that it generates a double ./wellknown is suspicious but I don't know how to set the msalConfig otherwise.

update: I have tried removing the .wellknown part of the url but it still doesn't work. The request looks better as it doesn't have a duplicate .wellknown bit but it doesn't have the p=B2C_1_sign_up_sign_in which I believe is essential.

Comment: Most likely your MSAL config is wrong since the URL constructed is wrong. Could you show how it looks like?

Comment: @juunas see above, I copied it from the "Run user flow" dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice in the sample the authority is defined as:

```
signUpSignIn: {
    authority: "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi",
},
```

So you should define the authority as:

```
https://zzz.b2clogin.com/zzz.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_sign_up_sign_in
```

Comment: Well spotted.  It should be available as a copy & paste from the user flow.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed that the authority endpoint returns the policy with the b2c_1 in lower case, even though in the Azure policy creation it prefixes upper case.

https://zzz.b2clogin.com/zzz.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_sign_up_sign_in