# AzureADB2C NextJS 13 Implicit Flow issue

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, next.js13

I keep getting this error message:
"AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the 'OAuth' Implicit flow.

However, I have checked in the manifest, it does say:
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,

I have selected both as per the document:
[image]

Spinning wheel for many days, any help will be appreciated.

Here is my [...nextauth].ts

```
 AzureADB2CProvider({
      id: "azureadb2c",
      clientId: process.env.AZUREADB2C_CLIENT_ID || "",
      clientSecret: process.env.AZUREADB2C_SECRET || "",
      tenantId: process.env.AZUREADB2C_TENANT_NAME || "",
      primaryUserFlow: "B2C_1_xxxxx",
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope:  "openid",
          response_type: "id_token",
          response_mode: "query",
          resource: "https://xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/1111111-1111-1111-1111-57911111114/publicInfo.Read",  
        },
      },
      checks: ["pkce"],
      client: {
         token_endpoint_auth_method: "none",
      },
    }),
```

Comment: Made some progress. Biggest change is moved the provider url to Web Redirect URI's from Single Page Redirect URI (Not clearly documented on official document).

Single page URI is having:
https://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/azureadb2c

and web redirect URI has now my provider URL

https://XXXX.b2clogin.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

Now, log in happens, and i get an oAuth profile back but then I get the following error:

OAUTH_PARSE_PROFILE_ERROR - 'Profile id is missing in Azure Active Directory B2C OAuth profile response.'

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Go to the Azure portal, find your Azure AD B2C tenant, and look at the user flows (policies) or custom policies if you are using them. Edit the user flow or custom policy to make sure the unique user identifier (such as `objectId` or another claim) is included in the token. If using a custom policy, make sure the output claims in your policy's technical profile include the `objectId` or the claim used as a unique identifier. In your Next.js application, you might need to configure the `profile` callback to extract the profile information correctly from the OAuth response.

Comment: Thanks VonC. 

Actually, I did find out that the Profile name is undefined, and mail is in an array, so I have added a profile function to the provider. Now my provider definition looks like this. 
```
profile(profile) {
        /* Profile was coming without id, email and name etc. So, I have added them manually. */
        let obj = {
          id: profile.emails[0],
          name: profile.name === undefined ? profile.emails[0] : profile.name,
          email: profile.emails[0],
          image: profile.picture || profile.avatar_url,
        }
        return obj
      }

```

Comment: I have edited the answer to address your last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```bash
+-----------------+            +-------------------+           +------------------+
|                 |            |                   |           |                  |
|   Next.js App   +------------> Azure AD B2C Auth +-----------> Token Generation |
|                 |  OAuth2    |   Implicit Flow   |   Tokens  |                  |
+-----------------+            +-------------------+           +------------------+
```

The issue could be from a mismatch in the configuration within Azure portal and your application code.
So double-check the Azure AD B2C settings in the Azure portal. Make sure that the 'Implicit grant and hybrid flows' are indeed enabled for your app registration (see "[Configure the Azure Active Directory B2C provider manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/configure/configure-azure-ad-b2c-provider-manual)" for illustration).

The manifest entries for [`oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` and `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reference-app-manifest#oauth2allowimplicitflow-attribute) should be set to `true`. You have confirmed this, but it might be worth revisiting the portal to make sure these settings are saved and active.

The `response_type` of "`id_token`" is used for implicit flow, but since you are using `pkce`, you might also need a `code` response type. [PKCE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636) (Proof Key for Code Exchange) is typically used with the [Authorization Code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/authentication-and-authorization#signing-in), not the implicit flow.

Make sure the scopes you are requesting match what is configured [in your Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#scopes). If you have custom scopes, they need to be defined in your B2C tenant.

The `authorization` endpoint should be the correct URL as per your B2C tenant configuration. Verify the endpoint URLs. Confirm that the [`tenantId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/trustframeworkpolicy) and [`primaryUserFlow`](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/azure-ad-b2c) are correctly named as per your B2C tenant details.

Check if CORS is properly set up in your Azure AD B2C settings to allow requests from your Next.js application's domain. See for instance "[Azure AD B2C CORS errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62474636/6309)".

The `resource` parameter in the `authorization` section should match the Application ID URI configured in your Azure AD B2C application settings.

---

> Actually, I did find out that the Profile name is undefined, and mail is in an array, so I have added a profile function to the provider. Now, my provider definition looks like this.
>
> ```
> profile(profile) {
>         /* Profile was coming without id, email and name etc. So, I have added them manually. */
>         let obj = {
>           id: profile.emails[0],
>           name: profile.name === undefined ? profile.emails[0] : profile.name,
>           email: profile.emails[0],
>           image: profile.picture || profile.avatar_url,
>         }
>         return obj
>       }
> ```

Note that using the email as the `id` is only appropriate if the email is guaranteed to be unique and consistent for each user. Typically, Azure AD B2C includes a dedicated `sub` (subject) or `oid` (object identifier) claim that should be used as the unique user ID.

Your handling of undefined `profile.name` is a good fallback. However, you should also make sure the `profile.emails` array exists and contains at least one email before attempting to access it.

You have provided for `profile.picture` or `profile.avatar_url` as potential sources for the user's image. That is fine as long as these claims are included in the token response from Azure AD B2C.

A slightly revised version of your `profile` function could be:

```js
profile(profile) {
  // Make sure profile.emails array exists and has at least one email.
  const email = Array.isArray(profile.emails) && profile.emails.length > 0
    ? profile.emails[0]
    : null; // Use null if emails array is not present or empty.

  // Use a consistent and unique identifier for the user's id.
  // The 'sub' claim is standard, but your Azure AD B2C configuration may use a different claim.
  const userId = profile.sub || profile.oid || email;

  // Construct the user object with normalized fields.
  let obj = {
    id: userId,
    name: profile.name || email,
    email: email,
    image: profile.picture || profile.avatar_url,
  }

  return obj;
}
```

That would check if `profile.emails` is an array and has at least one entry before attempting to use it, which prevents potential errors. It prefers standard claims like `sub` or `oid` for the user ID if they exist, falling back to email if necessary. And it sets `name` to the profile's `name` if it exists, otherwise falling back to the email.